# get key code with call function JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

when use JSF `inputText` call javascript function by ajax event keydown but not get code event of keu down.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Start Page</title>
    <script>
        i = 0;
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $("#form\\:inp1").keydown(function (e) {
                $("#form\\:span1").text(e.type + ": " + e.which);
            });
        });
        function keyUp1(e, extraval)
        {
            $("#form\\:span2").text(e.type + ": " + e.which);
            window.alert("call it" + extraval);
        }
    </script>
</h:head>
<body>
    <h:form id="form">
        JQuery:
        <p:inputText id="inp1" />
        <p:outputLabel id="span1" value="Test This"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <h:outputText value="JSF Ajax: " />
        <p:inputText id="counter" value="#{listenerView.text}">
            <f:ajax event="keydown" onevent="function(data) {keyUp1(data,'  Test it')};"/>
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputText id="out" value="#{listenerView.text}"/> 
        <p:outputLabel id="span2" value="Test This"/>
    </h:form>
</body>
```

first `inputText` work with Jquery and javascript function in line 11 but second `inputText` not work with JSF ajax.

Comment: I think this is only name argument and is not different what we call that.

Comment: is there a way for get keycode from outputText ?

Comment: I din't notice , you say if change argument from `data` to `Event` problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

The data that you receives is event - it contains event.type, event.status, event.source. Thats why it does not work for you.

You can catch the event keydown but in source u will find only HTMLInputelement - the inputText element that invoked the event - not the key.

If you realy need to know what key has been pressed then use your jQuery version, if you need to post request to backend and get some field update then use jsf ajax. BTW you are mixing primefaces component with jsf ajax - do not do that (it's not the same) - use primefaces ajax if you want.

Working version (just diff)

```
   function keyUp1(e)
   {
       if (e.status !== "complete") {
           console.log(e.type + ": " + Object.keys(e));
           console.log("type: " + e.type);
           console.log("status: " + e.status);
           console.log("source: " + e.source);
       }
   }

   <f:ajax event="keydown" onevent="keyUp1"/>
```